# Accessing Azure ServiceConfiguration settings in Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, iisnode

I'm coming to the beta deployment phase of building a Node.js application running through iisnode on Windows Azure. Having set up multiple instances, as well as production/staging separation, my research has led me to the following conclusion:

> If I want to change configuration settings on the fly without redeploying code, I need to use Service Configuration `.cscfg` files.

My problem is that I've stored various configuration settings in the `<appSettings>` and `<iisnode>` elements of `web.config` that I might want to change, which are currently exposed in my Node application via the process global object.

I've looked around [MSDN](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/how-to-configure-a-cloud-service/), [Node documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915562/what-is-the-relationship-between-web-config-connection-strings-and-serviceconfig) (the usual), and can't find if Node does or can expose Service Configuration settings in the same way. If not, is there a way I can expose them to my application?

**Edit:** To be more specific, I'm really only looking to move the `node_env` setting from `web.config` to Service Configuration, since I'd like to be able to switch from staging to production setup with just a config change. The reason - we're using IP switching to swap between staging and prod, and there are some very minor differences between the two (the URL of the RESTful web service it consumes, for example).

I also know I can configure `node_env` in an `iisnode.yaml` file read by iisnode, but that will still recycle the application, and I don't want to modify **x** yaml files and redeploy, where **x** is the number of instances of the production/staging application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the configuration settings via the Azure SDK for Node.js.

To install:

`npm install azure`

To get the configuration settings:

```
var azure = require('azure');

azure.RoleEnvironment.getConfigurationSettings(function(error, settings) {
  if (!error) {
    // You can get the value of setting "setting1" via settings['setting1']
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

These settings seem to be held in an XML file located in c:\Config\ folder of the Azure machine.

I'm certain that you're not *supposed* to access these directly, but you could easily parse this XML and read the settings when node starts.

Comment: I could easily be wrong, but I wouldn't agree that you're not supposed to access these - the API that comes with the Azure Cloud tools contains the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime assembly and namespace. Within that, the RoleEnvironment class provides a static method for accessing these configuration values at runtime. Great for C# and what have you, but not for Node.

Comment: I think he's saying you're not meant to read the XML file on the VM. (You're supposed to use the API.)